# The name for a type of map between vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, modules, vector-spaces

Is there a name for a map $f:V \to W$ between two $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces that is not linear map but which still staisfies
$$
f(\lambda v) = \lambda f(v), ~~~~~ \textrm{ for all } \lambda \in \mathbb{K}, ~ v \in V?
$$
I guess the additive structure of $V$ and $W$ is not so important so the question could just be asked about two sets equipped with an action of a field, which is to say two $G$-sets, where $G$ is the group of non-zero elements in $\mathbb{K}$.

Comment: [Homogeneous map of degree $1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function)?

Comment: Seems that is what I was looking for. Thanks you very much.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not need another was answer than that hort comment.